# Selenium Get WebElement inside a WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning Selenium and I have a question that, supposed we have something like below:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'>
  <div class='insider2'>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'>
  <div class='insider2'>
```

I can select a list of wrapper element using Css selector with **.wrapper** . So, suppose I have those elements, how do I select **insider1** or **insider2** using the wrapper WebElement that I've already had? I understand that there are many ways to select insider1 and insider2 but my question here is, Is it possible or not to select an inside element of a WebElement?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please revisit and clarify the question little bit more?

Comment: If your identify with Css selector or xpath of the given html code. That won't be identified on web page,b'coz there are two elements with same xpath/css selector. You should take xpath from its parent tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't identified which language so I'm going to answer with examples in Java.
You make the wrapper equal to a WebElement as follows (which you will get the first instance of back since you're using class instead of something unique but for the sake of argument lets say there's only one element with that class) and you should probably be closing your div's:

```
WebElement wrap = driver.findElement(By.className("wrapper"));
```

Then you can swap 'wrap' in, in place of your driver as a pointer and do the following to get at the dom tree elements

```
WebElement inside1 = wrap.findElement(By.xpath("div[1]"));
WebElement inside2 = wrap.findElement(By.xpath("div[2]"));
```

Comment: thanks, this is the element that i'm looking for. I didn't know that WebElement has findElement.