# Selenium invalid operation exception

Tags: selenium, invalidoperationexception

I have an issue I can't solve. Visual Studio throws an error when I use this code

```
IWebElement a = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='visit-i visit-i2 thumbs-img']"));
a.Click();
```

The error Visual Studio gives:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>       The program '[10768] Follow and like.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' 
>       has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
>       The program '[10768] Follow anit'sike.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has 
>       exited with code 0 (0x0).

Webpage code:

[image]

I would also like to click the highlighted button, but I get the same error.  I think I get the error because it's operated by an event handler, but if that was the problem, I wouldn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that `a` variable has value? it means that make sure that `driver.FindElement` method returns correct value.

Comment: if i'm understanding what your saying correctly then yes a 100% has value i have tried absolute path, css, classname, linktext.  all the same, I wouldnt see how all that results in same error

Comment: So which line throws this error? first line or second line?

Comment: omg lol your right its not getting a link i commented a.click(); and it still happens.  so the question now is why cant it find it?

Comment: in python we have `dir(OBJECT)` function which returns all methods and attributes of OBJECT. and we trace it easily. try to find something like this in your programming language to make sure that your object contains your required methods or attributes. good luck ;)

Comment: Maybe, this could help...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665219/selenium-get-webelement-inside-a-webelement