# Get number of words in a text

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Java and Selenium, and I have to extract the number of words in a specific text. I'm stuck because I get more results than I expected.

Considering the following HTML

```
    <div data-v-2f952c88="" class="text1">
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="ABC" class="description__section">
   <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
     <p>Headline 1
       Hello everyone i´m new at stack overflow</p>
     <p> And I need your help
        to get the total of words in this exemple
     </p>
   </div>
 </section>
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="DEF" class="description__section">
     <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
        <p>I Love Coding
            I use Java</p>
        <p> Another Text
            And Selenium
        </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<div data-v-2f952c99="" class="querty">
 <section data-v-3b755ad5b="" data-v-2f952288="" data-content-provider="DEF" class="description__section">
   <div data-v-051a18e7="" data-v-3b789d5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f962c88="">
     <p>This is another text along the WEBPAGE
       I don´t want to count this words in my total count</p>
    </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

In Java I've created this function:

```
    private String countWords(WebDriver driver){        
    int totalLetters = 0;     
        try{                               
            List<WebElement> className = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='text1']"));
            for(WebElement classElement: className){
                if(classElement!=null) {
                    String[] tags = {"p", "section"};
                    for (String tag: tags) {
                        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag));
                        for (WebElement element: elements) {
                            String text=element.getText();                        
                            String[] words = text.split("\\s+");                        
                            if (words!=null) {                            
                                totalLetters = totalLetters + words.length;                            
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    String s=String.valueOf(totalLetters);
    System.out.println("How many word? " + s);
    return s;
```

So my problem is that my function is extracting all the words inside every "p" and "section" tags in the webpage and I only wanted the "p" and "section" inside the first "div ..... class="text1" ".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `driver` in `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag))` instead of `className`. [Find Elements From Element - Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/#find-elements-from-element)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Get WebElement inside a WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665219/selenium-get-webelement-inside-a-webelement)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the image to check why it gives count of all 'p' and 'section' tag
[image]

Is this helpful to find your problem ?
Or your problem is that it is also giving the counts of class ='querty'?

```
<div data-v-2f952c99="" class="querty">
 <section data-v-3b755ad5b="" data-v-2f952288="" data-content-provider="DEF" class="description__section">
   <div data-v-051a18e7="" data-v-3b789d5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f962c88="">
     <p>This is another text along the WEBPAGE
       I don´t want to count this words in my total count</p>
    </div>
 </section>
</div>
```