# Using Python Selenium, how to do click on a webElement of webElements?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have figured out how to find a subelement of an element using Selenium in python using this Stack overflow post.

[Selenium Get WebElement inside a WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665219/selenium-get-webelement-inside-a-webelement)

I want to take it one step further.  I want to be able to perform actions on the subelement.  Going off the previous example:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'>
  <div class='insider2'>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'>
  <div class='insider2'>
```

I am trying to do something like

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div')
for element in elements:
    sub_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('//div')
    if sub_element.is_displayed()
        ActionChains(driver) \
            .move_to_element(sub_element ) \
            .click(sub_element ) \
            .perform()
```

Yes, I could just do sub_element.click() in this example but I want to do more types of interactions.

The example as is cannot find the element subelement.  And if I put `ActionChains(element)` instead of `ActionChains(driver)`, the code throws an error because element is a webElement and not a webDriver.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to close your html tags:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'></div>
  <div class='insider2'></div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='insider1'></div>
  <div class='insider2'></div>
</div>
```

And to select the inner tags I used this code:

```
outers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="wrapper"]')

for outer in outers:
    inners = outer.find_elements_by_xpath('./child::div')
    for inner in inners:
        print(inner)
```

You specify the class of the outer div's with:

```
'//div[@class="wrapper"]'
```

This way you don't accidentally select the inner one's as I think it happened with your code. Then you select all child elements of outer that are div's:

```
'./child::div'
```

Comment: You are right on the close tags.  I should have caught that one.  I think my focus is more on performing actions, like clicking, on the selected element once you have identified the inner element.  You did a great job finding the inner element but that was covered by the previous StackOverflow post(hyperlink).  I need help taking it one step further.

Comment: Have you tried to put the parent element into move_to_element like this: ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(sub_element).perform()

Comment: I just tried `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(sub_element).perform()` but the error I get is `(JavascriptException)Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite`

Comment: I think the error is that your xpath isn't definite. So instead of only one element the xpath you use points to multiple elements. Try to confirm that your xpath only points to one element. And also try to put in a wait condition: time.sleep(3).

Comment: the function `find_element_by_xpath` only returns the first occurrence for matching elements.  So I'm not sure that is the issue.  Even when the website is loaded fully, it get the error as well.  But those are good suggestions.

Comment: When I tried your code I came across the problem that the elements list contained all six div tags and not just the outer ones. Now if you iterate over all of them only the first and fourth one have sub elements. The second and third don't have sub elements and therefore they will throw errors. Can you please check if the first iteration gets executed without an error or if it already occurs in the first iteration. And can you please provide the full error code.